# how to override host at Amazon S3 client?

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

im using symfony2 as framework form my application, i want to connect to my ceph client as it is said in API (same as amazon s3).

composer.json:

```
    "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "dev-master",        
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "*",
    "amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php": "*"
```

im using gaufrette bundle to manage my filesystem

what i got so far is:

```
config.yml
    mydrive.aws_s3.client:
        class: Aws\S3\S3Client
        factory_class: Aws\S3\S3Client
        factory_method: 'factory'
        arguments:
            -
                key: %my_drive_s3_key%
                secret: %my_drive_s3_secret_key%
                region: %my_drive_s3_region%
knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        my_drive_s3_v2:
            aws_s3:
                service_id: 'mydrive.aws_s3.client'
                bucket_name: '%my_drive_s3_bucket_name%'
                options:
                    create: true
                    directory: '%my_drive_s3_directory%'
    filesystems:
        user_fs:
            adapter:    my_drive_s3_v2
            alias:      my_drive_filesystem
    stream_wrapper:
        protocol: data
```

so following the api's this is the way i'm connecting to amazon s3 serwers
but im not using amazon s3 serwers im using my own ceph serwers.
and my question is how i change the host in amazon s3 client ?

now it's like this:
`[curl] 56: Problem (2) in the Chunked-Encoded data [url] https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com`

and i want this 
`https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com` to be `https://mybucket.s3.custom.com`

here is the api i followed: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle#awss3

Comment: It looks like you are using only the AWS SDK for PHP 2.x adapter, so you do not need to include "amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php" in your composer.json.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `base_url` parameter.

```
config.yml
    mydrive.aws_s3.client:
        class: Aws\S3\S3Client
        factory_class: Aws\S3\S3Client
        factory_method: 'factory'
        arguments:
            -
                key: %my_drive_s3_key%
                secret: %my_drive_s3_secret_key%
                region: %my_drive_s3_region%
                base_url: https://mybucket.s3.custom.com
```

Please check the **AWS SDK for PHP User Guide** to see all of the [client configuration options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/configuration.html#client-configuration-options).